# Почему при записи в json возникает ошибка?

Tags: java

```html
2020-03-11 17:49:44.191  WARN 3436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 335544652, SQLState: 21000
2020-03-11 17:49:44.192 ERROR 3436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : GDS Exception. 335544652. multiple rows in singleton select
2020-03-11 17:49:44.310 ERROR 3436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL [select cancelledc0_.id as id1_1_, cancelledc0_.REG_CAPTION as reg_capt2_1_, cancelledc0_.REG_CODE as reg_code3_1_, cancelledc0_.VERSION as version4_1_, (select (case when lic.changing_doc_date is null then lic.action_date else lic.changing_doc_date end) from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id) as formula1_, (select lic.identity_card_number from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id) as formula2_, (select lic.is_not_returned from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id) as formula3_, (select (case when secondsel.lawyer_status = 4 then 30 when secondsel.lawyer_status = 2 then 20 when secondsel.lawyer_status = 3 then 10 else secondsel.lawyer_status end) from lawyers secondsel) as formula4_, (select l.PERSON_FIO from LAWYERS l where l.lawyer_status not in(1, 5)) as formula5_ from LAWYERS cancelledc0_ where cancelledc0_.VERSION=(select max(cancelledc1_.VERSION) from LAWYERS cancelledc1_ where cancelledc0_.id=cancelledc1_.id)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query] with root cause

org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: multiple rows in singleton select
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2103) ~[jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar:2.2.15-JDK_1.8 (build: tag=v2.2.15 date=201904061030)]
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2053) ~[jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar:2.2.15-JDK_1.8 (build: tag=v2.2.15 date=201904061030)]
 at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlFetch(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1318) ~[jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar:2.2.15-JDK_1.8 (build: tag=v2.2.15 date=201904061030)]
```

При помощи hql запроса создаю одну таблицу из нескольких, но при запуске приложения возникает ошибка.

```html
import java.util.List;
@Transactional
public interface CancelledCertificatesRepository extends JpaRepository<CancelledCertificates, Integer> {
    List<CancelledCertificates> findAll();



    @Query("select e from Lawyers e where e.version = (select max(b.version) from Lawyers b where e.id = b.id)")
    List<CancelledCertificates> findByCancelledCertificates();
        }
```

```html
@Service
public class CancelledCertificatesServiceImpl implements CancelledCertificatesService {
   private CancelledCertificatesRepository cancelledCertificatesRepository;
    @Autowired
    public void setCancelledCertificatesRepository(CancelledCertificatesRepository cancelledCertificatesRepository) {
        this.cancelledCertificatesRepository = cancelledCertificatesRepository;
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CancelledCertificates> findAll() {
        return cancelledCertificatesRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CancelledCertificates> findForExport() {
        List<CancelledCertificates> cancelled_certificates = cancelledCertificatesRepository.findByCancelledCertificates();
        return cancelled_certificates;
    }
}
```

```html
public interface CancelledCertificatesService {
    List<CancelledCertificates> findAll();
    List<CancelledCertificates> findForExport();
}
```

```html
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAWYERS")
public class CancelledCertificates {
    public CancelledCertificates() {
    }
    @Id
    @Formula("(select cdb.id from common_base_doc cdb where cbd.lawyer_id = lawyer_id)")
    private Long id;
    @Formula("(select (case when lic.changing_doc_date is null then lic.action_date else lic.changing_doc_date end)" +
            " from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id)")
    private Date changing_doc_date;
    @Formula("(select lic.identity_card_number from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id)")
    private String identity_card_number;
//    @Formula("(select PERSON_FIO from LAWYERS where STATUS_ON_PANEL = 'Прекращен')")
    @Formula("(select l.PERSON_FIO from LAWYERS l where l.lawyer_status not in(1, 5))")
    private String person_fio;
    @Column(name = "LAWYER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long lawyer_id;
    @Formula("(select lic.is_not_returned from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id)")
    private Integer is_not_returned;
    @Formula("(select (case when secondsel.lawyer_status = 4 then 30 when secondsel.lawyer_status = 2 then 20 " +
            "when secondsel.lawyer_status = 3 then 10 else secondsel.lawyer_status end) from lawyers secondsel)")
    private Integer lawyer_status;
    @Column(name = "REG_CAPTION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String reg_caption;
    @Column(name = "REG_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String reg_code;
    /*"select cbd.id,
             (case
     when secondsel.lawyer_status = 4 then 30
     when secondsel.lawyer_status = 2 then 20
     when secondsel.lawyer_status = 3 then 10
             else secondsel.lawyer_status end) as reason_id,
     lic.is_not_returned as not_returned,secondsel.reg_caption,secondsel.reg_code,lic.identity_card_number as cert_number,
             (case
     when lic.changing_doc_date is null then lic.action_date
     else lic.changing_doc_date end) as cert_date,
     secondsel.id as lawyer_id,secondsel.person_fio as fio

     from lawyers secondsel, (select id, max(version) as version  from lawyers group by id) firstsel
     join common_base_doc cbd on cbd.lawyer_id = firstsel.id
     join LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic on lic.id = cbd.id
             where
     secondsel.id = firstsel.id
     AND secondsel.version= firstsel.version
     and secondsel.lawyer_status not in (1,5)"*/

  public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getChanging_doc_date() {
        return changing_doc_date;
    }

    public void setChanging_doc_date(Date changing_doc_date) {
        this.changing_doc_date = changing_doc_date;
    }

    public String getIdentity_card_number() {
        return identity_card_number;
    }

    public void setIdentity_card_number(String identity_card_number) {
        this.identity_card_number = identity_card_number;
    }

    public String getPerson_fio() {
        return person_fio;
    }

    public void setPerson_fio(String person_fio) {
        this.person_fio = person_fio;
    }

    public Integer getIs_not_returned() {
        return is_not_returned;
    }

    public void setIs_not_returned(Integer is_not_returned) {
        this.is_not_returned = is_not_returned;
    }

    public Integer getLawyer_status() {
        return lawyer_status;
    }

    public void setLawyer_status(Integer lawyer_status) {
        this.lawyer_status = lawyer_status;
    }

    public String getReg_caption() {
        return reg_caption;
    }

    public void setReg_caption(String reg_caption) {
        this.reg_caption = reg_caption;
    }

    public String getReg_code() {
        return reg_code;
    }

    public void setReg_code(String reg_code) {
        this.reg_code = reg_code;
    }
}
```

В сущности есть sql запрос

```html
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private LawyersService lawyerService;
   // @Autowired
//    private OOrderChangeFIOService oOrderChangeFIOService;
    @Autowired
   private ForeignLawyerService foreignLawyerService;
    @Autowired
   private CancelledCertificatesService cancelledCertificatesService;

    @Value("${C:\\Users\\Senko_KL\\IdeaProjects\\converttabletojson}")
    private String exportDirPath;

    //@GetMapping(value = "/run")
   @PostMapping("/run")
    public String export() {
        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-Hms");
            final String dbFile = sdf.format(date) + "-lawyers.json";
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            final JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
            final ObjectNode node = factory.objectNode();

            List<Lawyers> lawyers = lawyerService.findForExport();
           // List<OOrderChangeFIO> changeFioFilters = oOrderChangeFIOService.findForExport();
            List<ForeignLawyer> foreignLawyers = foreignLawyerService.findForExport();
            List<CancelledCertificates> cancelledCertificates = cancelledCertificatesService.findForExport();

            ArrayNode nodeLawyers = objectMapper.valueToTree(lawyers);
          //  ArrayNode nodeChangeFioFilters = objectMapper.valueToTree(changeFioFilters);
            ArrayNode nodeForeignLawyers = objectMapper.valueToTree(foreignLawyers);
            ArrayNode nodeCancelledCertificates = objectMapper.valueToTree(cancelledCertificates);

            node.set(Lawyers.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name(), nodeLawyers);
         //   node.set(OOrderChangeFIO.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name(), nodeChangeFioFilters);
            node.set(ForeignLawyer.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name(), nodeForeignLawyers);
            node.set(CancelledCertificates.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name(), nodeCancelledCertificates);
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File(exportDirPath, dbFile), node);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```html
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-11 16:17:16.572 ERROR 6232 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/github/steed777/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.CannotForceNonNullableException: Identifier property [private java.lang.Long com.github.steed777.model.CancelledCertificates.id] cannot contain formula mapping [(select cdb.id from common_base_doc cdb where cbd.lawyer_id = lawyer_id)]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Sql запрос:

```html
"select cbd.id,
            (case
    when secondsel.lawyer_status = 4 then 30
    when secondsel.lawyer_status = 2 then 20
    when secondsel.lawyer_status = 3 then 10
            else secondsel.lawyer_status end) as reason_id,
    lic.is_not_returned as not_returned,secondsel.reg_caption,secondsel.reg_code,lic.identity_card_number as cert_number,
            (case
    when lic.changing_doc_date is null then lic.action_date
    else lic.changing_doc_date end) as cert_date,
    secondsel.id as lawyer_id,secondsel.person_fio as fio

    from lawyers secondsel, (select id, max(version) as version  from lawyers group by id) firstsel
    join common_base_doc cbd on cbd.lawyer_id = firstsel.id
    join LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic on lic.id = cbd.id
            where
    secondsel.id = firstsel.id
    AND secondsel.version= firstsel.version
    and secondsel.lawyer_status not in (1,5)"
```

Как изменил сущность:

```html
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAWYERS")
public class CancelledCertificates {
    public CancelledCertificates() {
    }
    @Id
   // @Formula("(select cdb.id from common_base_doc cdb where cbd.lawyer_id = lawyer_id)")
    private Long id;
    @Formula("(select (case when lic.changing_doc_date is null then lic.action_date else lic.changing_doc_date end)" +
            " from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id)")
    private Date changing_doc_date;
    @Formula("(select lic.identity_card_number from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id)")
    private String identity_card_number;
//    @Formula("(select PERSON_FIO from LAWYERS where STATUS_ON_PANEL = 'Прекращен')")
    @Formula("(select l.PERSON_FIO from LAWYERS l where l.lawyer_status not in(1, 5))")
    private String person_fio;
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long lawyer_id;
    @Formula("(select lic.is_not_returned from LAWYER_IDENTITY_CARD lic, common_base_doc where lic.id = common_base_doc.id)")
    private Integer is_not_returned;
    @Formula("(select (case when secondsel.lawyer_status = 4 then 30 when secondsel.lawyer_status = 2 then 20 " +
            "when secondsel.lawyer_status = 3 then 10 else secondsel.lawyer_status end) from lawyers secondsel)")
    private Integer lawyer_status;
    @Column(name = "REG_CAPTION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String reg_caption;
    @Column(name = "REG_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String reg_code;
    @Column(name = "VERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer version;
```

Comment: тут поле `id` вычисляемое, не очень понятно как собираетесь делать hql подзапрос `(select max(b.version) from Lawyers b where other.id = b.id)` с таким вычисляемым id (@Formula над полем id), можете привести пример sql запроса, который должен сформироваться?

Comment: Прикрепил sql запрос.

Comment: Зачем так громоздить формулами, сделайте отдельный класс-вьюху и напишите в нём свой запрос в аннотации `@Subselect`

Comment: в sql запросе используется поле таблицы, а именно `secondsel.id` , а в сущности над id стоит формула, формируется неправильный запрос. @Formula над полем id должно быть перенесено в отдельное поле в сущности, а над id не должно быть этой аннотации

Comment: Изменил код, запустилось приложение, но потом появилась ошибка.

Comment: это уже ошибка firebirdsql, нужно в hql запросе поменять `where e.version = (` на `where e.version in (` , почему то = не поддерживается ((, [подсмотрел сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628968/multiple-rows-in-singleton-select-how-to-make-several-results-appear)

Comment: Дело не в этом, выскакивает та же ошибка, к тому же есть другая сущность и похожий запрос.

Comment: Может быть связано, если таблица другой сущности называется так же?

Comment: похожий запрос нужно поправить. Название таблицы не играет роли, главное правильно сформировать sql запрос. Ошибки на это я не вижу, не могу подсказать